# PrintPreviewDialog: How to show multiple pages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I can do this at runtime through `PrintPreviewDialog`'s toolbar, but how can I do this programmatically? There's no obvious property or method to do this. Googling didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. You need to access it through `PrintPreviewDialog.PrintPreviewControl.Rows` and `PrintPreviewDialog.PrintPreviewControl.Columns` properties to show multiple pages. Hope it helps someone.